# & in function parameter after type

Tags: c++, function, parameters, reference

In a class, we have this:

```
friend Circle copy(const Circle &);
```

I know that usually to pass something by reference you use & before the name of the variable, but in this case there is no name of variable.....what is this exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a function declaration; you don't need parameter names in those, only in the definition of it. Somewhere else, there will be something like

```
friend copy(const Circle& other) {
  // method implementation
}
```

Comment: You mean `Circle copy(const Circle &other)`, right? It's a friend function, so it's *not* a member.

Answer (score 2):

That is the declaration of a friend function.  In general, when you declare a function, you do not need to name the variables in its argument list.  Most people usually do name them, but sometimes it's obvious and they're omitted.  It doesn't change anything--the name of a variable in a declaration is mere documentation--it's the name in the definition that counts (and can legally differ from the name in the declaration).

As for what "friend" means in C++, I'll leave you to look that up online.

Comment: FWIW you don't *have* to name the parameters in a definition either. You just can't access them if you don't, so it's only useful to leave out the name if they're unused for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In function declaration mentioning parameters name is not necessary.

```
friend Circle copy(const Circle &);
```

Where as in function definition paramerter(s) name is required

```
friend Circle copy(const Circle &rhs)
{
.....

}
```